# Set up Brew installed Python 2.7.X as sdk for Intellij / Pycharm

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am trying to import the brew installed version of python by emulating the `Global Libraries` structure existing for the (mostly) working mac os built-in 2.7.2.  However IJ is unable to infer the types or to create the library properly.

**Update**  this is a large existing project. Creating a *new* project just to get a different version of python is not an option.

Here are the steps:

Try to create new Global Library: **Fail** : no python .
[image]

OK, so I use Copy to clone the built-in SDK:

[image]

Now - let us try to emulate the paths included in the original built-in but with the brew base dir: here is a starting point:

[image]

And here is one of the exact entries from the builtin library:

[image]

So let us clikc on the `+` to add it:

[image]

So .. IJ is unable to handle it properly.  I also tried a half dozen others - all with same **shrug** result from IJ.

So then what is the correct process?

**Update**  Here is the project SDK dialog (thanks to scribbles).

[image]

And trying to add:  **but the "OK" button is not enabled!  So then IJ is not able to load it..

[image]

Comment: Do you actually have the PyCharm plugin correctly installed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe   Yes and I checked for updates just no.    Intellisense is working for python but there is a problem with one of the libraries that i want to try out the brew version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New Project -> Select SDK.

See [this video](https://youtu.be/eqpBTw5dO9w) if you still have any questions.

EDIT: Is this more along the lines of what you're looking for ([link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html#d1278485e69))? 
[image]

Comment: I have a large existing project - this is **not** an option.  I will update the OP.

Comment: @javadba - updated my answer. let me know if that is more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Well yes but the OP shows a screenshot that Python is not in the "new" SDK type list

Comment: @javadba - there is a difference between updating the global library and the project library. The OP shows you attempting to add a new global library, no? Also a library != an SDK. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/sdk.html) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/library.html)

Comment: (not recognized..)  thx for that clarification . Looking into it.

Comment: An screenshot from the docs  isn't terribly helpful; please write it out properly, which makes it more accessible.

Comment: Hi -  the comment from scribbles *is* helpful - I was in global instead of project level.  I have updated the OP to show the rsult: the project SDK can not be imported from the Brew version. Can you take a look at the bottom of the updated OP?

Comment: given this post has already helped i have upvoted: hopefully we can get the whole way.

Comment: @javadba were you able to get it figured out? Have been away from my computer. Glad to continue helping if needed.

Comment: Your answer was part of the solution. I actually needed to invalidate caches and restart IJ. 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but but I ran into the same problem with the current Python 2 install from homebrew in High Sierra. Instead of choosing a directory like it needed in the previous setup, I just setup the Python SDK pointing to the python executable link in /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin (which is the directory I added to my path for Python 2. It seems to be working just fine now.

Hopefully this will help someone.